# Log data into cassandra using c#

Tags: c#, .net, cassandra, datastax

I trying to log data into Cassandra using c#. So my aim is to log as much data points as I can in 200ms. 
I am trying to save time, random key and value in 200ms. Please see code for refrence. the problem how can I execute session after while loop.

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder()
                   .AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
                   .Build();
ISession session = cluster.Connect("log");  //keyspace to connect with

var ps = session.Prepare("Insert into logcassandra(nanodate, key, value) values (?,?,?)");

stopwatch.Start();
while(stop.ElapsedMilliseconds <= 200)
{
    i++;
    var statement = ps.Bind(nanoTime(),"key"+i,"value"+i);
    session.ExecuteAsync(statement);
}
```

Comment: ExecuteAsync should return some promise/future/... that you need to wait on... But in your case, it's not an execution of actual query - it's just acceptance of it for execution... What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: @AlexOtt As i mentioned in question, I am trying to log as many data I can in 200ms. So I made a while loop which run for 200ms and log data into cassandra. As I am using ExecuteAsync inside while loop, I think it is slowing down process.
Is there any other way around for doing this????

Answer (score 0):

Please prefer [System.Threading.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) with a `TimerCallback` over `Stopwatch`.

---

EDIT: (*reply to the comment*)

Hi, I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but here are some general concepts about async calls and parallel execution. In .NET world the async is mainly used for **Non-blocking I/O operations**, which means your caller thread *will not wait for the response* of the I/O driver. In other words, you instantiate an I/O operation and dispatch this work to a "thing" which is outside of the .NET ecosystem and that will gives you back a **future** (a `Task`). The driver **acknowledges** back that it received the request and it **promises** that it will process it once it has free capacity.

That `Task` represents an async work that either succeeded or fail. But because you are calling it asynchronously you are not awaiting its result (**not blocking the caller thread to wait for external work**) rather move on to the next statement. Eventually this operation will be finished and at that time the driver will notify that `Task` that a request operation has been finished. (The Task can be seen as the primary communication channel between the caller and the callee)

In your case you are using a **fire and forget** style async call. That means you are firing off a lot of I/O operations in async and you forget to process the result of them. You don't know either any of them failed or not. But you have called the Casandra to do a lot of staff. Your time measurement is used only for firing off jobs, which means you have no idea how much of these jobs has been finished.

If you would choose to use `await` against your async calls, that would mean that your while loop would be **serially executed**. You would firing off a job and you can't move on to the next iteration because you are awaiting it, so your caller thread will move one level higher in its call stack and examines if it can processed with something. If there is an `await` as well, then it moves one level higher and so on...

```
while(stop.ElapsedMilliseconds <= 200)
{
    await session.ExecuteAsync(statement);
}
```

If you don't want serial execution rather **parallel**, you can create as many jobs as you need and await them as a whole. That's where `Task.WhenAll` comes into the play. You will fire off a lot of jobs and you will await that single job that will track all of other jobs.

```
var cassandraCalls = new List<Task>();
cassandraCalls.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(_ => session.ExecuteAsync(statement)));
await Task.WhenAll(cassandraCalls);
```

But this code will run until all of the jobs are finished. If you want to constrain the whole execution time then you should use some **cancellation** mechanism. `Task.WhenAll` does not support `CancellationToken`. But you can overcome of this limitation in several way. The simplest solution is a combination of the `Task.Delay` and the `Task.WhenAny`. `Task.Delay` will be used for the timeout, and `Task.WhenAny` will be used to await either the your cassandra calls or the timeout to complete.

```
var cassandraCalls = new List<Task>();
cassandraCalls.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(_ => ExecuteAsync()));
await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(cassandraCalls), Task.Delay(1000));
```

In this way, you have fired off as many jobs as you wanted and depending on your driver they may be executed in **parallel** or **concurrently**. You are awaiting either to finish all or elapse a certain amount of time. When the `WhenAny` job finishes then you can examine the result of the jobs, but simply iterating over the *cassandraCalls*

```
foreach (var call in cassandraCalls)
{
    Console.WriteLine(call.IsCompleted);
}
```

I hope this explanation helped you a bit.

Comment: As i mentioned in question, I am trying to log as many data I can in 200ms. So I made a while loop which run for 200ms and log data into cassandra. As I am using ExecuteAsync inside while loop, I think it is slowing down process. Is there any other way around for doing this????